# How to get attribute in JSP from servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I want to get a request attribute in my JSP page after completing an action. In my doPost the set up is like this:

```
String operation = request.getParameter("operation");

if(operation.equals("someAction")) {
  //Do something
} else if (operation.equals("otherAction")) {
  if (someParameter != null){
   //Doing a for loop
   //When loop is finished (so outside for loop)
      request.setAttribute("msg", "Attribute message");
      request.getSession().setAttribute("msg2","Session message");       
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/Absolute/path/Final.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

This code gives me no message at all after completing the method, BUT, if I refresh the page suddenly the session message appears. I want the message to appear immediately, so `req.setAttribute` seems like what I want. I added the absolute path because with a relative one the program entered an infinite loop.

Relevant parts of my JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<p>
    Message from request: <b><%= request.getAttribute("msg") %></b>
    <br />
    Message from session: <b><%= session.getAttribute("msg2") %></b> //<---This is the only one that works (after refresh)
    <br />
    Message from EL: <b>${msg2}</b>
    <br />     
    Message from EL: <b>${msg3}</b>

</p>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:8080/MaJSPProject/MainServlet/*",
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: {pTableData:JSON.stringify(TableData), operation:"submitLFoodTable", dropdownField: document.getElementById('dropdownField').value},
   success: function(msg){
       // return value stored in msg variable
       console.log(msg);
   }
```

});

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it like `JSP1 - > Post Request - > Servlet (Mentioned above) -> Render JSP2 (Mentioned above)` ?

Comment: On the whole the code looks correct. Only possible reason I can think of is JSP is rendered before Servlet setAttribute is called.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao No, it's like JSP1 -> Post Request  - > Servlet -> Render message on JSP1

Comment: Ok, Is the JSP getting re-rendered after the post? And the value is wrong even after re-render?

Comment: Post the code, where you are making the post call.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao, added it to the main post.

Comment: Its an ajax request which will not update the page with the response from the server. If you want it to work as you have coded, you need to use normal Form Post instead of ajax.

Comment: The JSP page does not re-renders after ajax call. And hence it does not gets the values you set on the server.

Comment: I'm going to try it, thank you!